# Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I keep getting the `data type mismatch in criteria expression` error message when I try to run the parameterized sql statement in VB.Net to a ms-access db (.accdb).

The problem is with `@PartNumber`, that much I know because I hardcoded it directly to get the value from the array, and it worked. I just don't know how to fix it.

`PartNumber` in the table is a TEXT field, and it is a string in VB.Net, its length is 20 in the table and is nowhere near 20 in the vb form being read in.

Here is the problematic code:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To trackParts.GetUpperBound(0) - 1
   If (trackParts(i, 4) = "1") Then
      cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ServiceParts ([IncidentNumber], [PartNumber], [Quantity]) Values (@IncidentNumber, @PartNumber, @Quantity);"
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncidentNumber", incidentNumberLabel.Text()
                     .ToString().ToUpper().Trim())
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumber", trackParts(i, 0)
                     .ToString.ToUpper().Trim())
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(trackParts(i, 3)))
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   End If
Next
```

Thanks in advance for any help, and if there is anymore information needed just let me know and I will post it. I will also update this with new things I have tried as I think of new things to try.

Comment: Post the table definition. It's likely a mismatch with the table's defined column types and your data.

Comment: Try assigning `trackParts(I,0)` to a temporary variable of the correct type, and using the temp in the `AddWithValue` call.

Comment: How should I post table definition? It is too long to post the text.

But the PartNumber in the table is data type TEXT and what I am sending to it I put ToString(), on top of the fact that it is String data type anyway.

EDIT: Pieter, I already tried that. Gave same error.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with the debugger to see what `trackParst(i, 0)` is when you make the call?

Comment: I have, and it comes out good for me. I also threw a messagebox just before the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(). The value is as expected. :/

Answer (score 0):

While this is not really an answer *per se*, it is the **exact** code that works correctly for me in Visual Web Developer 2010. The only change I made to the contents of your `For` loop is that I changed the loop end condition from `trackParts.GetUpperBound(0) - 1` to `trackParts.GetUpperBound(0)` because my array of test data only had one row.

Table: [ServiceParts]
IncidentNumber - Text(255)
PartNumber - Text(255)
Quantity - Number(Long Integer)
(No PK, no indexes.)

See if there's something in here that is slightly different from what your code is doing:

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim trackParts(0, 4) As String
        trackParts(0, 0) = "PartNumber01"
        trackParts(0, 1) = "filler"
        trackParts(0, 2) = "filler"
        trackParts(0, 3) = "3"
        trackParts(0, 4) = "1"

        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\__tmp\testData.accdb;"
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        cmd.Connection = con
        For i As Integer = 0 To trackParts.GetUpperBound(0)
            If (trackParts(i, 4) = "1") Then
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ServiceParts ([IncidentNumber], [PartNumber], [Quantity]) Values (@IncidentNumber, @PartNumber, @Quantity);"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncidentNumber", incidentNumberLabel.Text().ToString().ToUpper().Trim())
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumber", trackParts(i, 0).ToString.ToUpper().Trim())
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(trackParts(i, 3)))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        Next
        con.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```